# REST API to send message from Publisher to Subscriber (MQTT) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rest, microservices, mqtt

Recently, I got a new task in a completely new topics (MQTT, REST-API and Microservices).

The **task** is as follows:

1. I have to create 2 Microservices which needs to communicate with each other via MQTT.
2. The Publisher should have a REST-API, which triggers the sending of message(string) from publisher to subscriber(console/log).

**Things I have Done:**

As I am familiar with .Net, started to do with it. Created a UI application as Publisher and Console application as Subscriber.

Installed mosquitto server in my machine and published a message (input from UI) and received it on Subscriber end.

**Questions:**

1. I need to have REST Api in Publisher side, which triggers and publish message to broker. How to create one in .Net?
2. Can I actually consider the 2 Applications I created as Microservices?
3. Can I complete this whole task in .Net?

As I am overwhelmed with information in Internet, I couldn't decide with the Proceedings of this task.

I have experience in ASP.NET MVC, Winforms, C#.

Can someone help me by clarifying my doubts? Any help is much Appreciated..!!

Comment: API needs someone to call them, when do you want to publish messages? and Yes you can complete the task in .net

Comment: @viveknuna Thanks for the response. In the UI, I am having a button and in that click event I am planning to publish the message (which I receive from UI).